# I have a problem with getting the return type of Balance from "ink::env::call::build_call" and the contract keeps panicking when called

Tags: ink, rust

```
let selector: [u8; 4] = [0xbd, 0x77, 0x15, 0xef];
let amount_out = build_call::<DefaultEnvironment>()
    .call_type(Call::new().callee(self.liquidity_pool_address))
    .exec_input(
        ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(selector))
            .push_arg(amount)
    )
    .returns::<u128>()
    .fire();

match amount_out {
    Ok(output) => return output,
    Err(_) => {
        panic!("Failed to execute call")
    }
}
```

The method with the selector: 0xbd7715ef returns a u128 (Balance) type. It doesn't ever have an Err variant, but instead returns 0.
The liquidity_pool_address is also its deployed contract address
And it takes one u128 argument

There are no error messages to help me debug the problem with the call.

Any clues?

Comment: You can and should edit your original post :)

Comment: Please include the error code thrown specifically as well above

Answer (score 2):

A minimal reproducer would be helpful for answering the question in more depth. So ideally code for a message in contract A and a message in contract B.

That being said, the issue in this case is often that either the selector doesn't exist or the contract doesn't exist.

Try the following:

Instead of

```rust
let selector: [u8; 4] = [0xbd, 0x77, 0x15, 0xef];
...
ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(selector))
```

you can write:

```rust
ExecutionInput::new(Selector::new(ink::selector_bytes!("my_message")))
```

This will automatically compute the selector bytes, ensuring that there was no mistake when transforming it manually to a byte array.

For `self.liquidity_pool_address`: Check if you do any castings to `AccountId` here. Sometimes I see contracts that do some weird stuff to get a `String` into `AccountId`.

You could try having a message `fn test(&self, acc_id: AccountId)` that contains the code you posted above, but instead of `self.liquidity_pool_address` it would use the message argument `acc_id`. This way you can test it with a properly typed `AccountId`; `polkadot-js`, Contracts UI and `cargo-contract` will automatically transform the supplied account id to the correct type.